Decompile versioned transaction with ATL
Given this a mock versioned message
{
   addressTableLookups: [...],
   compiledInstructions: [...]
}

I try with versioned transaction without ATL this code below ran successfully.
   const messageV0 = new MessageV0(message);
   console.log('decompiled', TransactionMessage.decompile(messageV0));

But when the transaction does have ATL includes in addressTableLookups the decompile throw an error
index.js:12623 Uncaught (in promise) Error: Failed to get account keys because address table lookups were not resolved
    at MessageV0.getAccountKeys (index.js:12623:13)
    at TransactionMessage.decompile (index.js:13492:33)

I think because the decompile the second argument in decompile method but how to convert addressTableLookups in MessageV0 object to the ATL when decompiling

Transaction without ATL mean the addressTableLookups is empty

This is because the data in the referenced address table lookups are required to decompile a message. The message only contains the index within the lookup, so you need to fetch the lookup table from on chain to resolve that to the actual addresses.
decompile takes a second argument for this: https://solana-labs.github.io/solana-web3.js/types/DecompileArgs.html
You can provide an arugment with one of these two shapes:
{
  accountKeysFromLookups: {
    readonly: PublicKey[],
    writable: PublicKey[], // you need to populate these with the addresses in your lookup tables
  }
}

// or

{
  addressLookupTableAccounts: AddressLookupTableAccount[];
}

AddressLookupTableAccount is a class in web3js: https://solana-labs.github.io/solana-web3.js/classes/AddressLookupTableAccount.html
One way to fetch it is with connection.getAddressLookupTable(): https://solana-labs.github.io/solana-web3.js/classes/Connection.html#getAddressLookupTable
Note that the input message (the first argument to decompile) has an addressLookupTables that you can use to find all the address lookup tables that you need to fetch.

Note that in the new version of web3js (currently in tech preview) there is a function decodeTransactionMessage that will fetch and resolve the address lookup tables for you: https://github.com/solana-labs/solana-web3.js/blob/3ae70f0f8ecac462847af6d2170945c118d4f0d6/packages/library/src/decode-transaction-message.ts#L45

Thanks for your answer

Here is my code. But the connection always return null. I used QuickNode RPC..
Am I wrong at somethingng?

The account that I received from compile version transaction is look like this
1111111111111111111G9KJrgUXSBpnzqR3MH

You don't need to do any of that. The addressLookupTables returns an array of objects with the shape: {accountKey: PublicKey; readonlyIndexes: number[]; writableIndexes: number[];}. You just need to look up the accountKey.
